# Existing project run with Laravel homestead (5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, virtual-machine, homestead

I have installed Laravel homestead it's working fine. my problem is how I map existing project to homestead? my *Homestead.yaml* file as bellow

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:

    - map: D:/www/Laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel  


sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public



databases:
    - homestead
```

This project generated from Homestead I have another exist project and how to map homestead.I added following code to *Homestead.yaml* file but it was not working.

```
 - map: D:/www/MyProject
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/MyProject
```

Please anyone can help me Thank you.

Comment: Did you re-provision your Homestead vm? use this command `vagrant reload --provision`

Comment: Also you'll need to add a site which maps to the public folder of MyProject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should edit your `folders` section to map to you `www` directory

```
folders:

    - map: D:/www
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

this will allow you to store all of your projects within D:/www directory and all of them will be mapped to your VM.

now you can add your Site

you should add this under **Sites**

```
 - map: my-project.app
   to: /home/vagrant/Code/MyProject/public
```

this assumes that your project is located at D:/www/MyProject

---

also don't forget to add new domain to your `hosts` file

```
192.168.10.10    my-project.app
```

and run `vagrant reload --provision`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:

    - map: D:/www/
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/


sites:
    - map: MyProject.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/MyProject/public


databases:
    - homestead
```

Make sure that:

1) There is a **code** folder inside C:/users/{currentuser}/

2) You have MyProject folder in D:/www

3) A virtual hosts file entry:
Vagrant box IP MyProject.app

And at last fire `vagrant reload --provision` command within C:/users/{currentuser}/Homestead folder